# Mocha after и this.slow() / this.timeout() - как подружить?

Tags: javascript, node.js, юнит-тесты, mocha

Есть один длинный тест, после которого надо подчистить следы. Я использую [after](https://mochajs.org/#hooks) hook, но время его выполнения больше стандартных 2000ms, из за чего весь тест failed.

```
Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
```

Для тестов предусмотрена возможность [изменять этот таймаут](https://mochajs.org/#test-duration), но с after это не работает. У меня такое ощущение, что я упустил что-то очень простое..

**UP:**

Я сделал пример, который больше похож на мой реальный тест и на котором можно воспроизвести проблему:

```
function long_async_function(cb){
    setTimeout(cb,3000);
}
function clear_test_data(cb){
    describe('clearing test', function() {
        this.timeout(3333);
        it('clear data and test it',function(done){
            long_async_function(function(){
                done();
                console.log('Clearing test call after callback');
                cb();
            });
        });
    });
}
describe('long test', function() {
    this.timeout(3333);
    it('do something',function(done){
        long_async_function(done);
    });
    after(function(done){
        this.timeout(12000);
        clear_test_data(done);
    });
});
```

В таком виде тест выполняется 18 секунд. Если изменять таймаут в after, время выполнения теста меняется пропорционально. After hook вызывает fail всего теста из за превышения таймаута, но при этом как показывает консоль - его done вызывается, но после ошибки с таймаутом. Что я не так сделал?

Comment: А как именно вы изменяли таймаут? Можете привести минимальный кусок кода иллюстрирующего проблему?

Comment: Конечно, сейчас приведу. Просто тут всё на примерах из документации можно воспроизвести

Comment: У меня просто уже почти готов ответ. Но он существенно зависит от того, как именно вы меняли таймаут :)

Comment: Вот, привел пример (писал на глазок, поскольку мой тест очень длинный и приводить его куски тут было бы дольше)

Comment: А для чего вы делаете `describe` в `after` хуке. Бред какой-то

Comment: http://pastebin.com/2vcf4Muc

Comment: Потому что функции удаления тоже надо тестировать

Comment: Так а причем тут хуки-то?

Comment: Потому что тестам нужны тестовые данные, которые после этого надо удалить. Параллельно протестировав функции удаления у модуля, работающего с бд.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33371/discussion-between-dmitriy-simushev-and-darth).

Comment: Там есть еще before hook, который все эти данные пишет из файлика куда надо

Answer (score 1):

Ваша проблема в том, что вы опосредованно используете `describe` в хуках (`after`, `before` и прочих). Так делать **категорически** нельзя.

Пытаться угадать, почему вы получаете таймаут выполнения тестов бессмысленно, т.к. вы неверно работаете с тестовым фреймворком. Mocha так **не работает**!

Правильным решением проблемы является полное переписывание тестов с разделением кода собственно тестов (`describe` + `it`) и кода инициализации/финализации окружения (хуки: `after`, `before`, ...).

И да, проблема не имеет ничего общего с `this.timeout`/`this.slow`, так как эти функции работают отлично.